# How to deal with answer coming from the original asker providing my solution?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I wrote an answer with 3 minimal changes to the code provided in the question. At this moment I got a downvote and a comment from the owner of the question saying "awesome. it works great!..."

The asker integrated my suggestions with the original code and posted the full reviewed code in another answer.

What can I do in this situation?

1. Remove my answer
2. Incorporate the full code reviewed in my answer
3. Remove the answer provided by the asker
4. Other

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49853896/binding-together-the-tables-created-in-a-loop/49854470#comment86725532_49854470) in question

Comment: The 1st option is not making any sense.. Its OP's question not yours. Also its not OP who downvoted since they dont have the privilege to downvote answers yet. Not sure you can do anything other than improve your own answer with explanation etc. and hope for upvotes over time

Comment: Sorry, the 1ft point is "remove my answer" (edited), I know the downvote come from someone else because the asker approve in the comment the answer.

Comment: As that OP has never accepted an answer but on occasion *does* comment that some answer works, he may be unaware what that gray tick things at the left are for and that they can turn green. (And he'll actually gain some points for making it do that.) It would not suprise me since he is lacking the `Informed` badge. Maybe someone ought to tell 'im this.

Comment: It is not what you think it is, the OP does not have enough rep to vote.  Deriving another answer from an existing post is explicitly encouraged by the site license.  He didn't get the attribution quite correct, that is easy to fix.  Done.

Comment: Same thing happened [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48856837/trying-to-get-all-imgs-from-web-python-bs4) (and for many other answers). Even sharing this: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) doesn't help with some new users.

Comment: Thanks for the link @KeyurPotdar, this will be usefull.

Comment: `5. Post about it on Meta SO and ride the upvotes due to the Meta Effect`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, Your comment ought to be the accepted answer to this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Remove my answer

If you feel that the other answer(s) are better than yours (or that your answer is otherwise not useful in general), and that you can't improve your answer, then sure.

> Incorporate the full code reviewed in my answer

If you think that makes your answer a better answer, then sure.  If you don't feel that it improves your answer, then don't.

In my eyes this mostly comes down to a determination as to whether readers of your answer are likely to be able to incorporate the answer into their code on their own or not.  Given that you have pretty compelling evidence that readers *do* have enough information from your answer (given that the OP successfully did so) I don't see this as necessary, but if you think it would be useful anyway, that's your call.

> Remove the answer provided by the asker

You have no means to do this yourself, and no grounds by which to have anyone else do so.

> Other

Clearly someone feels that your answer, as is, is not useful.  Try to figure out what about it might be seen as problematic and that could be improved.  Is something unclear, is there a better solution to the problem (or a better way of implementing the general approach you choose), is your answer well explained, is it sufficiently complete, is the answer a useful answer in general, that's likely to actually help others solve their problem, etc.

Comment: Probably I will remove my answer, I still think that is the better one, but I'm collecting downvote (for some reason) and I don't like it.

Comment: @Terru_theTerror Metaeffect ftw....

Answer (score 3):

I always prefer to check facts if I can. Let me join "other side" for a moment:

---

09:57 --- you [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/366075/revisions) the answer with 2 points

10:39 --- you add third point

10:59 --- OP post his answer with his working code

12:22 --- you ask on meta

12:58 --- you copy/paste code from OP answer into yours

13:18 --- @Servy answer on meta

---

And next day the OP answer is downvoted and deleted.

> The asker has integrated my suggestions with the original code and posted the full reviewed code in another answer

This is totally fine to take someone *pseudo-code* or suggested solution, then **adapt** it and post as an answer. Maybe (I am not blaming) your answer lack **very important for OP** detail, which makes your answer slightly less than perfect.

I did the same (posting own answer) several times and I am going to do so.

The main aim is to make the best answer for future readers. So they don't have to waste time, thinking of how to adapt your pseudo-code or fighting other problems your answer didn't mentioned.

Of course this can be abused. So if there is a tendency (I am not checking this) - the OP should be warned, his answer deleted, etc.

> What can I do in this situation?

Asking on meta (after trying google-fu, someone may asked similar question) is the best and you did it right. Other points are answered by @Servy.

What you did wrong:

- Acting before you receive the answer, why do you ask then?
- Copy/paste code from other answer. This is called plagiarism.

Comment: First asker's comment (removed) to my answer was "awesome. it works great! I will post all the code in another answer", or similar so I think that the answer was well detailed and not lacking of details
A few things about what you are sayng I did wrong
I integrated my answer after the comment of  @Suraj Rao "...improve your own answer with explanation etc." because it was a good suggestion and I was not able to predict if a good answer would have arrived 
I don't think that it was a copy/paste but the only way to integrate my suggestion in the original code
why are you giving me a liar?

Comment: @Terru_theTerror, I don't see deleted comments in [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49854470/timeline). And this is how it looks to me. Perhaps some moderator can have a look and if you are not lying, then I'll apologize and will delete last part. Since the OP posted code earlier it may be copy/paste or not. I don't know. I only wanted to act as [devil's advocate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil%27s_advocate). Why? Maybe because I am jealous to 20+ upvotes you got. Maybe I am a bad person. But what if I am right?

Comment: A moderator intervention is good for me, I will ask to a moderator to make things clear. I don't want any kind of suspicious about my work/reputation. About the tonne of upvote, I'm the first surprised about what happened after this question.

Comment: No one but moderators can see deleted comments. The OP indeed posted *awesome. it works great!. i'll post the whole script.* as a comment on the answer. I deleted the *Thanks for the suggestion* comment as it appeared to refer to the first revision only.

Comment: Some friendly advice: know that as a community member you can never see the whole picture, even as a 10k user. Please go easy on calling anyone a liar.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thanks. I'll remember that and will be careful next time.

Comment: @Terru_theTerror, sorry about blaming you in lying. I was wrong. I've removed that part from the answer.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters for the clarification, I still don't like the tone of Sinatr's answer, he accuses me of plagiarism and brutal copy/pasting but at least it's clear that I'm not a liar.